# How to UPDATE a different values of same column from a table using Nested Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table - Sample

| Column_A | Column_B |
| --- | --- |
| 00000067 | 01-02 |
| 00000078 | 03-04 |
| 00000097 | 05-06 |

I want to split the values of Column_B using the delimiter '-', place the second part in Column_A.

I have written below query which gives me syntax error ( Error occurs at this 'from': from (SELECT Column_A.....)

`Update Sample a  SET Column_A = New_Sample_Table.New_Column  from (SELECT Column_A , Column_B, SUBSTR(Column_B, instr(Column_B, '-') +1) AS New_Column  from Sample b) New_Sample_Table  WHERE a.Column_B = New_Sample_Table.Column_B;`

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your description is correct and you didn't miss to tell us anything important, you don't need a subquery for that. You can do something like this:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET column_a = 
CONCAT(column_a,'-',SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_b,'-',-1)) 
WHERE column_b LIKE '%-%';
```

`SUBSTRING_INDEX` will find the substring right from the "-" in the second column. `CONCAT` will put the two strings and the "-" together.
The `WHERE` clause prevents that the first column will be updated if the second column doesn't contain a "-".

If it's not intended to put the "-" to the first column, but only the substring after that, just remove this from the `CONCAT` part:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET column_a = CONCAT(column_a,SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_b,'-',-1))
WHERE column_b LIKE '%-%';
```

See here a working example according to your sample data: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LY9FCxlD)

Comment: Thank you Very much . This helped a lot :). By the way I dint want to concat the value . Hence removed concat function from the script : UPDATE yourtable SET column_a = 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_b,'-',-1)
WHERE column_b LIKE '%-%';